# SSR rendering exceeded timeout, fallbacking to CSR for (all routes)

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I created a new angular project and ran the following command:
`ng add @spartacus/schematics --baseUrl https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/ --baseSite=electronics-spa --ssr`. After, I ran the command `npm run dev:ssr`, opened http://localhost:4200 and found the following problem:

[image]

Any ideas how to correct this bug and make the app run SSR instead of CSR? This warning message is showing for every route I try to access.

(https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10638)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's because of SSR optimization feature available in Spartacus 3.0 and up.

You can either extend the timeout in your `server.ts` (passing a second parameter to `NgExpressEngineDecorator.get` method) or set it to 0, so it won't be fallbacking to CSR at all. Here is an example:

```
const ngExpressEngine = NgExpressEngineDecorator.get(engine, { timeout: 0 });
```

You can use API documentation to get a list of available options:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus/interfaces/SsrOptimizationOptions.html

Additionally, an extended documentation regarding this feature is on its way and should be available soon.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue, but changing timeout does not help!

The root cause is: the certificate of Commerce Cloud is invalid, as it is self-assigned.
Because I am using local commerce, with URL: localhost://9002

And the workaround is:

Add below config to package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:ssr": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ng run mystore:serve-ssr",
},
[...]
"devDependencies": {
    [...]
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0"
}
```

Then run following to start Spartacus

```
yarn dev:ssr
```